# Masking HTML Form Text Field with asterisk

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a situation where we are encoding and then sending the phone number entered by user in the Form text field to the back end.
So when the user hits submit button the value of the Phone Number text field is encoded and same encoded value becomes visible in the text field till the next page loads. And if user hits the back button he would still see the encoded values which again is a bad user experience.

This encoded value may confuse the users.
Is there is solution where we can just show asterisk instead of the encoded value and at the same time the back end receives the same encoded phone number.

Please share your views on this.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Please share your code samples.

Comment: I suggest to show blank values for that field
OR
change the input type to "password"

Comment: I thought of doing it but that would be problem if used hits back button and come to Form page. The text field would stay as password field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden field, then when the form is submitted, populate the hidden field with the encoded phone number.  Then change the value of the visible phone to *****.

Answer (score 1):

You can change type of input field from `<input type="text" name="fieldname">` to `<input type="password" name="fieldname">` or hide it `<input type="text" name="fieldname" style="display: none;">`

Comment: This wont be solution to this as in case user comes back to previous page using back button he would find the text field missing.

Comment: Why do you convert user input in text field? You can get input value to variable and convert it without changing input field.

Comment: You can empty text input value after submit.